# Does Smaato provides sdk of Symbian^3?

Tags: 3d, symbian, nokia-wrt

Currently, we are working on 3-D Game on Symbian^3 platform. Now I need to implement ads in my Game(preferably via Smaato). I have also checked out Smaato's website for SDK, but there I found SDKs for Symbian S60, WRT and Qt. There is no SDK specially for Symbian^3 on Smaato's website. I am a bit confused now.

Moreover, we are using Carbide C++ editor for writing our Symbian^3 Game application. What I should do, in order to implement ads via Smaato on Symbian^3 platform.

Thanks,

ATUL PRAKASH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Smaato website](http://www.smaato.com/symbian/) says about their Symbian support:

> Key Facts
>
> - Easy integration
> - Compatible with Qt 4.6 and Qt 4.7
> - Allows ad display in QWidget and Qt Quick based applications
> - **Multi platform: runs on Symbian S60 3rd & 5th edition Symbian ^3 and Maemo**
> - Targeting: gender, age, keywords, search queries, carrier and location
>     (GPS & ZIP)
> - Beacons support: required for ad networks to get high priced CPM
>     campaigns
> - Asynchronous loading of display ad (no wait time for users)
> - Flexibility to set time controlled ad rotations
> - Supports banner and text ads
> - Low resource consumption

It has a picture of their ads running on a Nokia N8 too, a Symbian^3 phone. So you should be able to use the same SDK.

Comment: On Smaato's website there are 3 SDK's regarding Symbian i.e. one for S60, other for Qt and last one for WRT. If they are saying that Smaato SDK is multiplatform then same SDK should run on Symbian^3. Which among these 3, I should use?

Comment: If your game is in native Symbian C++ (which I suspect it is), then use the S60 one. Otherwise if it is in Qt, use that one. It's very unlikely your game is in WRT -- Web Runtime -- mostly for widgets and things.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to email Smaato and ask. After all, they have a vested interest in providing it to you if they have it available.

Comment: I have already mailed my query to Smaato two days ago. But still I am waiting for their reply.